# Using netcat to setup a bind shell on localhost, but having issue with '-e' flag

Tags: ubuntu, netcat

I'm trying to do a simple exercise, where I need to set up a "server" hosting a bind shell, using netcat. On my localhost.
I'm running ubuntu 20.04

I'm following [this](https://stuffjasondoes.com/2018/07/18/bind-shells-and-reverse-shells-with-netcat/) tutorial, that has this simple line for doing it:

```
nc -nvlp 5555 -e /bin/bash
```

But, when I copy-paste this bit, netcat is confused by the `-e` flag:

```
netcat: invalid option -- 'e'
```

Removing the `-e` flag is'nt much help either. In that case , netcat just prints it's usage instructions.
Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

checking my netcat version:

```
ask@Garsy:~$ netcat -h
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.206-1ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every version of `netcat` includes the `-e {command}` option. For example, on my version of Debian the documentation (see `man netcat`) for the OpenBSD-derived version I've got installed writes this,

> There is no `-c` or `-e` option in this `netcat`, but you still can execute a command after connection being established by redirecting file descriptors. Be cautious here because opening a port and let anyone connected execute arbitrary command on your site is DANGEROUS. If you really need to do this, here is an example

It then goes on to show how to implement command redirection with a couple of examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just me doing exercises locally. I have added an edit with the version I am using, do you have any guess as how I could get the bind up and running?

Comment: Read the man page. _It then goes on to show how to implement command redirection with a couple of examples._

Comment: Or install a different version of `netcat`, I suppose

Comment: The man page is a bit cryptic to me, they use this example `cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f`  Are they maybe just saying that I can use pipes to specify that I want to open a shell when I open the connection?

Comment: @NotQuiteSo1337, installing `netcat-traditional` might be the easier way out